# Throwing a string in a Grunt task doesn't make it fail

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

As far as I know, the following ways of throwing errors are ok:

```
throw new Error('spam');
throw 'spam';
```

However, when I throw `'spam'` in a grunt task, it doesn't fail. When throwing an actual `Error` it does. Why does it behave differently for those cases?

I am using strict mode.